# Can't resolve method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent); - Open URL on android device

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to call a function to open a browser with a given url but get this error message.

I looked at those two question and understand I probably have a context problem but still couldn't quite understand how to resolve it.

[Cannot resolve method startActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173043/cannot-resolve-method-startactivity)

[Cannot find symbol method startActivity(android.content.Intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872245/cannot-find-symbol-method-startactivityandroid-content-intent)

My code:

```
public void openWeb(String url) {
    String fullUrl = "http://bit.do/"+url;
    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(fullUrl);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what kind of class are you trying to do this? Does it extend `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `Application`

Comment: It extends `Activity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that this method is in a class that does not have access to a context. So you can either pass the context from the activity that uses this method or place this method within the class of that activity.

Answer (score 3):

You shall get a context from the constructor like this:

```
public class YourClass{
   private Context context;

   public YourClass(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }
   ...
   public void openWeb(String url) {
      String fullUrl = "http://bit.do/"+url;
      Uri webpage = Uri.parse(fullUrl);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
      if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
         context.startActivity(intent);
      } 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will have to pass the uri using intent.setData. Try doing this way,

```
String url = "your url";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using `fragment`

**Try :**

```
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Here `getActivity()` returns the `context`

Comment: I tried that and got a "Cannot resolve method getActivity()" instead